# Matlab nested for loop too Slow

Tags: matlab

Following Nested For loop in matlab too slow, I want to reduce the time used for following process, any help to improve the situation shall be highly appreciated.

```
R =0;
C =0;
Ch=0;

MyImage = imread('Test1.TIF');
[R, C, Ch] = size(MyImage);

L1 = 2.3; 
L2 = 14.1;  
Q1 = 1; 
Q2 = 255; 
K1 = 200; 
K2 = 1000; 
E = 1.1;
RCPV = zeros(R, C);
V = zeros(R, C);
T = zeros(R, C);
for C = 1:C
    for R = 1:R
        PV(R,C) = impixel(MyImage,C,R);
        PV(R,C) = mean(PV(:));
        %PV(R,C) = PV;
        V(R,C) = ((L2-L1)/(Q2-Q1))* (PV(R,C)-Q1) + L1;
        T(R,C)= (K2/log(((K1*E)/V(R,C))+1))-273; 
    end
end

xlswrite('testdata.xlsx',T);
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? Are you sure you shouldn't be indexing with `I` and `J` instead of `R` and `C` inside your loop?

Comment: Really Sorry, you are right R = 7000;
C1 = 8000;
A = [R,C];
B = [R, C];
D = [R,C];
  for I = 1:C
    for J = 1:R
      % some assignment
      A(J,I) = L; 
      B(J,I) = M-N; some basic math. formula 
      D(J,I) = G*B(J,I); some basic formulaFormula
    end
 end

Comment: Please update the question and include the correct code.

Comment: If you just preallocate your memory, you should see a very significant speedup. So before your loop `A = zeros(R,C); B = zeros(R,C); D = zeros(R,C);` instead of assigning them to `[R,C]`.

Comment: Are the basic math formulas just dummys or the ones you would like to vectorize?

Comment: These are dummys, final results of D(J,I) are stored in excel file

Comment: Preallocating memory using A = zeros(R,C); B = zeros(R,C); D = zeros(R,C) still slow, recursion or some other function may be more helpful, as i am not much expert in matlab programming therefore unable to implement recursion etc, on this code

Comment: Can you provide more information on the mathematical functions? What are their inputs?

Comment: In Matlab, like in most programming languages, using loops is typically faster than recursion.

Comment: Until we know the relationship between `L,M,N,G` and `I,J`, this is unanswerable. Unless there is no relationship, in which case the replacement for the first line in the loop is trivially `A = L;`.

Comment: I updated the code and formulas

Comment: I am still waiting for the reply from experts

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `parfor` instead of just `for`. It would be better for number of iterations like 7000x8000.

it could be like

```
parfor loopvar = initval:endval
   statements;
end
```

You can have inner loop i.e. `J` running in parallel manner. Try different ways too :)